# Drawing two perpendicular tangent line from the origin to $y=x^2-2x+a$

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, quadratics, curves, tangent-line

We drew two perpendicular tangent line from the origin (the point $(0,0)$ )  to the curve $y=x^2-2x+a$. what is the value of $a$?

$1)\frac54\qquad\qquad2)\frac{-5}4\qquad\qquad3)\frac34\qquad\qquad4)\frac{-3}4$

At first I realized that we can write the quadratic equation as  $y=(x-1)^2+(a-1)$ so the graph is obtained by moving $y=(x-1)^2$ upward or downward by $a-1$.

Also at the point $x=\alpha$ on the curve, the slope of the tangent line is $2\alpha-2$ . And I also know that the multiply of the slopes of perpendicular tangent lines is $-1$.

But I'm not sure how should I use these information to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the tangent lines concretely, you can do it by the process of elimination:

The three values $-\frac{5}{4}, -\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ are not possible. Why? The peak is then below $0$. That means that one tangent has to point below the $x$-axis, however, the other tangent line has to reach the left side of the parabola and therefore go beyond the $y$-axis to the left. That means no angle of $90$ degree is possible.

In fact, for the first two values, you cannot even draw any tangent from $(0,0)$ as this point will lie above the parabola.

That means the only possibility is $a = \frac{5}{4}$. I've added an image of GeoGebra to show that this really works out

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let the tangent be $y=mx$, (as it passes through the origin), then we have the quadratic $x^2-(m+2)x+4-4a=0.$ In order for the given line be tangent to the given parabola, it must intersect at only one point, and hence ($B^2-4AC=0).$ So we get a quadratic for $m$ as $m^2+2m-4(1-a)=0.$ This means that two tangents are possible, and they will be perpendicular if $m_1m_2=-1 \implies 4(1-a)=-1 \implies a=5/4$ (product of roots of a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c = \frac{c}{a}$)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^2-2x+a\require{cancel}$.

A line passing through $(0,0)$ is of the form $y=\lambda x$. If such a line is tangent to the graph of $f$ at some point $(\alpha,\beta)$, then:

1. $\beta=f(\alpha)=\alpha^2-2\alpha+a$;
2. $\lambda=f'(\alpha)=2\alpha-2$.

So, you have$$\beta=\lambda\alpha=2\alpha^2-2\alpha\quad\text{and}\quad\beta=\alpha^2-2\alpha+a,$$and therefore $2\alpha^2\cancel{-2\alpha}=\alpha^2\cancel{-2\alpha}+a$. So, $\alpha=\sqrt a$ or $\alpha=-\sqrt a$. In the first case, $\beta=2a-2\sqrt a$, and in the second case $\beta=2a+2\sqrt a$. In the first case, the slope of the tangent line will be $2\sqrt a-2$, and in the second case it will be $-2\sqrt a-2$. The only situation in which the tangent lines will be orthogonal, that is, the only case in which the product of these numbers is $-1$, is when $\sqrt a=\pm\sqrt{\frac54}$. Therefore, $a=\frac54$.

Answer (score 1):

You had a good part of what you needed when you completed the square for the quadratic polynomial, in which you established that the vertex of the corresponding parabola has the coordinates $ \ (1 \ , \ a - 1) \ \ . $  So the axis of symmetry of this "upward-opening" parabola is "to the right" of the $ \ y-$axis, which requires that the tangent line from the origin to the parabola "to the left" of that axis be *negative* (the graph **LegNaiB** provides illustrates this).  The slope of the other tangent line from the origin must therefore be positive; as the vertex is on or above this tangent line, we conclude that $ \ (a - 1) \ $ is positive, which is only true for choice $  \mathbf{(1)} \ \ . $

We can cinch this by considering the tangent points on the parabola.  You found that $ \ \frac{dy}{dx} \ = \ 2x - 2 \ \ , $ so the tangent point "to the right" of the $ \ y-$ axis, $ \ x_1 > 0 \ , $ is given by $$   x^2_1 - 2x_1 + a \ \ = \ \ (2x_1  -  2) · x_1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a \ = \ x^2_1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x_1 \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{a} \ \ . $$
This tangent line then has the slope $ \ m \ = \ 2·(\sqrt{a} - 1) \ > \ 0 \ \ , $ which makes it plain that $ \ a > 1 \ \ . $

[Were this not a multiple-choice problem, we might go on to determine the second tangent point, $ \ x_2 < 0 \ , $ by finding intersection(s) of the parabola with the tangent line of negative slope, thus:
$$ x^2_2 - 2x_2 + a \ \ = \ \ -\frac{1}{2·(\sqrt{a}  -  1)} · x_2 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ 2·(\sqrt{a}  -  1)·x^2_2  \ +  \ (-4\sqrt{a}  +  5)·x_2 \ + \  2·a·(\sqrt{a}  -  1) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ ,  $$
a quadratic equation for which the discriminant is $$   \Delta \ \ = \ \ (-4\sqrt{a}  +  5)^2 \ - \ 16·a·(\sqrt{a}  -  1)^2 \ \ = \ \ 32·a\sqrt{a} \ - \ 16a^2 \ - \ 40\sqrt{a} \ + \ 25  $$ $$ = \ \ (5 - 4a) \ · \ (4a - 8\sqrt{a} + 5) \ \ . $$
The discriminant has a rational zero, $ \ a \ = \ \frac54 \ \ , $ and the other two zeroes are complex numbers.  There is then a single intersection point of the line from the origin for this value of $ \ a \ \ , $ again confirming choice $ \mathbf{(1)} \ \ . $
The tangent lines are therefore $ \ y \ = \   (\sqrt5 - 2)·x \ $ and $ \ y \ = \ -(\sqrt5 + 2)·x \ \ , $ with the tangent points at $ \ x_1 \ = \ \frac{\sqrt5}{2} \ \ $ (thus, "to the right" of the vertex) and $ \ x_2 \ = \ -\frac{\sqrt5}{2} \ \ . $ Curiously, the tangent points are at equal "horizontal distances" from the $ \ y-$axis, despite the asymmetrical location of the parabola.]